Storing large amounts of stream data from SDR for later recall
I am building an app that connects a front-end web interface with a variety of connected backend SDRs. The user controls the sample rate of the radios. It is quite feasible that this app could go into the gigahertz of complex samples, which as I understand it, will quickly accumulate into gigabytes of data every second.
At the time, the app is currently merely passing through frames of data every 1/60 seconds and discarding the rest, so the app can handle the intake. However, one of the features I have been tasked with implementing is being able to take a limited "capture" of recent raw historical data. This will require me to store the data in some manner and be able to recall it at mercy. I estimate that the return payload of these files could most certainly be in the gigabytes.
I have explored a number of options on the internet, but many external solutions seem to be more suited for streaming data related to business. Additionally, I considered writing the data to disk, but I think this will become too slow to write and recall at high sample rates.
What are some strategies I can employ here?
